# iterating through list of maps with one loop and multiple string creation statements

Tags: terraform

I have the following code:

```
locals {
   all_nodes_verbose_etcd = [for k, v in var.virtual_machines:
                               format("%s ip=%s etcd_instance=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address, v.etcd_instance)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes_verbose      = [for k, v in var.virtual_machines:
                               format("%s ip=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) == 0]

   master_nodes           = [for k, v in var.virtual_machines:
                               v.name
                               if v.worker_node != true]

   etcd_nodes             = [for k, v in var.virtual_machines:
                               v.name
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]
}
```

Is there anyway this can be changed such that I only need one for loop ?

My virtual_machines list of maps looks like this (not the whole thing - but enough to provide an idea of what it looks like):

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  default = {
    "master1" = {
       name          = "z-ca-bdc-master1"
       worker_node   = false
       etcd_instance = "etcd1"
       ipv4_address  = "192.168.113.79"
       ipv4_netmask  = "22"
       ipv4_gateway  = "192.168.112.1"
       dns_server    = "192.168.112.2"
       ram           = 8192
       logical_cpu   = 4
       disk0_size    = 40
       disk1_size    = 0
    },
    "master2" =  {
       name          = "z-ca-bdc-master2"
       worker_node   = false
       etcd_instance = "etcd2"
       ipv4_address  = "192.168.113.80"
       ipv4_netmask  = "22"
       ipv4_gateway  = "192.168.112.1"
       dns_server    = "192.168.112.2"
       ram           = 8192
       logical_cpu   = 4
       disk0_size    = 40
       disk1_size    = 0
    },
```

This is psuedo code for what I would like:

```
locals {
   for k, v in var.virtual_machines:                            
   all_nodes_verbose_etcd = [format("%s ip=%s etcd_instance=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address, v.etcd_instance)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]

   all_nodes_verbose      = [format("%s ip=%s", v.name, v.ipv4_address)
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) == 0]

   master_nodes           = [v.name
                               if v.worker_node != true]

   etcd_nodes             = [v.name
                               if length(v.etcd_instance) > 0]
}
```

Comment: You forgot to specify what is `var.virtual_machines`. Same as before? Also what do you mean by "multiple string creation statements"?

Comment: I'll paste it into the question, give me 5 seconds . . .

Comment: Also what do you mean by "multiple string creation statements"?

Comment: What I'd like to get to if possible is to build each string, but have just a single for k, v loop or something that achieves the same end result - does that help ?

Comment: I've added psuedo HCL at the end of the question for the thing I would like to achieve

Comment: Sadly, you can't do this. You can't dynamically create variables like this. The closest you could get maybe is to have a `map` with keys of `all_nodes_verbose_etcd`, `all_nodes_verbose` and so on, but this would be similar to what you already have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227997/discussion-between-chrisadkin-and-marcin).